# Java WireMock defining stubs fail in multithreaded tests with Cucumber parallel execution

Tags: java, cucumber, wiremock

I have Spring-Boot application and integration tests using Cucumber and WireMock.
Executing tests in regular non parallel execution mode works fine without any issues, but when switched to parallel with `cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled` as `true`, it started to fail. Exception:

```
com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.JsonException: 
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : 10,
    "source" : {
      "pointer" : "/code"
    },
    "title" : "Error parsing JSON",
    "detail" : "Unrecognized field \"code\" (class com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.Errors), not marked as ignorable"
  } ]
}
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.JsonException.fromJackson(JsonException.java:53)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.common.Json.read(Json.java:60)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.safelyExecuteRequest(HttpAdminClient.java:519)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.executeRequest(HttpAdminClient.java:489)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.executeRequest(HttpAdminClient.java:466)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.addStubMapping(HttpAdminClient.java:146)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.register(WireMock.java:414)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.register(WireMock.java:409)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.givenThat(WireMock.java:115)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.java:119)
```

Does `WireMock.stubFor` supposed to be a thread-safe operation? Based on exception, looks like nope. If non thread-safe, which workarounds are possible (synchronize / lock all executions of `stubFor`)?

Example of stub initialization:

```
WireMock.stubFor(post(urlPathMatching("/test"))
    .withRequestBody(equalToJson(..))
    .willReturn(aResponse()
        .withStatus(200)
        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .withBody(..)));
```

WireMock is created in the following way:

```
WireMockServer wireMock = new WireMockServer(options()
    .port(8000)
    .extensions(new ResponseTemplateTransformer(true))
    .notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(true)));
wireMock.start();
configureFor(8000);
```

version:  `com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8-standalone:2.33.0`

Comment: You have two problems. One being that your Wiremock dependencies are not consistent with each other. As a result your Wiremock cliënt does not understand the error from the Wiremock sever. This is causing the error you see now. The second being that what ever caused the Wiremock server to send you an error message in the first place. You want to solve the second problem, but you can not see the details of that problem until you solve the first problem.

Comment: wiremock client and server - in what maven dependencies they are present? cause now I have only transitive dependency to `com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-jre8-standalone`

Comment: Couldn't say, you didn't share enough information to reproduce your problem. Wiremock did move from `com.github.tomakehurst` to `com.wiremock` at some point. That may be a cause, but that's just a guess.

Comment: If you start debugging at `HttpAdminClient.safelyExecuteRequest` you can probably see what the server actually sends back.

Comment: ok, thank you, I will try to figure out that. but the main complication is that it works without any issues in non parallel test execution

Comment: Yes, but you can't see what causes that problem right now. Sometimes you gotta shave a Yak first.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje issue was due to taken wrong WireMock server port, executed from another thread, and response failed with 404 error code. As this response is not from WireMock server,  payload wasn't deserialized into `Errors` class from WireMock library. Thank you for trying to help and providing some useful hints!

Comment: Congratulations! That wasn't something I would have expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After substituting class `com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient` in my repo and adding extra logs, it was discovered that response body during stub definition execution is `{"code":"404.null.55","message":"Not Found"}`.
The issue was that request targeted wrong port, it took a default port 8080 instead of configured 8000. In my case, port 8000 was configured for WireMock server and 8080 for Tomcat from Spring Boot test.

Initially, when Spring context starting, code configures WireMock server with port 8000 from thread `main` in the following way:

```
WireMockServer wireMock = new WireMockServer(options()
    .port(8000)
    .extensions(new ResponseTemplateTransformer(true))
    .notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(true)));
wireMock.start();
configureFor(8000);
```

and later, `WireMock.stubFor(..)` is invoked from another thread (due to parallel execution mode by Cucumber). Due to implementation inside `WireMock`, it has thread local `defaultInstance`, which should be additionally configured with appropriate port from invoked thread.

So I updated code to invoke `WireMock.configureFor(8000);` before each invocation of `WireMock.stubFor(..)` to guarantee that port is configured per each required thread, and it fixed the issue.

The initial exception that I faced with as `JsonException Unrecognized field 'code'` is due to not properly handling 404 client error code inside [HttpAdminClient](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/blob/2.33.0/src/main/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/client/HttpAdminClient.java#L518-L519), as this error not from Wire Mock server, but might be from any other server (indeed it's a rare case, but still might happen).
I will either open an issue or contribute a fix to WireMock to have a descriptive error with explicitly specifying used port in case of 404 error code, so library will handle such cases gracefully.